# If $f(x,y)= x^{x^{x^{x^y}}} + (\log x)(\arctan(\arctan(\arctan(\sin (\cos xy-\log (x+y)))))$ Find $D_2f(1,y)$

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

Here we $D_2 f(1,y)$ means we have to calculate the partial derivative w.r.t $y$, so I have applied one short tricks that I have put $x=1$ in the equation then $f(1,y)= 1+0=1$ so the $D_2(f(1,y)=0$. Now my question is that the way I have gone is it correct or not. Please comment and give solution if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes, it's correct, and it's a lot shorter than Math-fun's answer.

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{d}{dy}f(x,y)=x^{x^y+x^{x^{x^y}}+x^{x^y}+y} \log ^4(x)+\log{x} \frac{d}{dy}\Big(\arctan\left(\arctan\left(\arctan(\sin (\cos (x y)-\log
   (x+y)))\right)\right)\Big)$$

Hence $$\frac{d}{dy}f(x,y)\Big|_{x=1}=0.$$

Comment: I'm having some difficulties to see why "the hence" works?

Comment: because $\log(1)=0$..hence? ps I have not checked the calculations in detail ;)/.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net 
$1^{1^y+1^{1^{1^y}}+1^{1^y}+y}\log^4(1)+\log(1) \times \alpha$ where $\alpha$ is a function a of $y$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f(1,y)=1$ for all $y \neq 0$ (it is undefined at $y=0$), we have $$\left.\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\,f(x,y)\right)\right|_{x=1}=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}y}\,f(1,y)=0\,.$$